# Have teamcity checkout on build agent machine

Tags: macos, build, rake, teamcity, perforce

We have a team city server installed on a server named pluto. It's a Windows Server machine. There is a build agent on Pluto used to do VS related builds.

We have another build agent connected to this TeamCity server instance called YOSX, a build agent that is running on Mac mini Yosemite.

I've created a build to build a solution on YOSX with rake script. As a VCS Root Checkout option I've selected Automatically on Agent.

Ok, I am expecting that perforce p4 app will be called by TC agent on YOSX machine, but when I run a build, I get an error:

```
Collecting changes in 1 VCS root (2s)
[Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] VCS Root details
[VCS Root details] "eyeleo.mac.dev" {instance id=98, parent internal id=31, parent id=Desktop_EyeLeoMac_EyeleoMacDev, description: "perforce: p4.radacode.net:1666: perforce stream: '//EyeLeo.Mac/dev'"}
Failed to collect changes, error: Unable to find P4 command-line client at path '//Applications/p4' on pluto for user PLUTO$
```

Why is trying to checkout on pluto with user $PLUTO while I specifically set it to checkout on build agent's machine.

P.S. Yes, I've set the build requirements so that the build configuration in question is only compatible with YOSX build agent.

Comment: can you post a snapshot of the image for your vcs checkout rules

Answer (score 1):

The server does not try to checkout the sources, but it still collects the information about changelists: modified files, commit messages etc.
This information will be used to display diffs, relevant issues, to track possible causes of test failures.

Please, install p4 on the PLUTO as well.

Comment: P4 is on Pluto, its just as I mentioned Pluto is a Windows machine and YOSX is Mac OS, so path to p4 that is set in vsc root will not allow pluto to execute checkout. Its ok, the problem was due to the fact that YOSX had p4 file without execute permissions and therefore was falling back to pluto.

Answer (score 1):

In my case p4 file on YOSX (build agent machine) was in PATH, but didn't have execute permissions. chmod +x p4 solved the puzzle.